# How to keep a sticky service alive with no executing code in main thread?

Tags: java, android, service, event-handling

My application has a service which needs to stay alive even after the user closes it (by swiping it away). My service prints log messages every second in a parallel thread.

Although it does return `START_STICKY`, it gets terminated as soon as the application is closed by the user. Here is my `onStartCommand` method:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    instance = this;
    Log.i("Service", "started");
    new Thread(() -> {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            Log.i("Service", "#" + ++i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    start_recording(null);


    return START_STICKY;
}
```

I've also declared it in the manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:stopWithTask="false"
/>
```

How can I prevent the system from killing the thread upon application exit? No other SO post has provided me with a solution which works.

Comment: maybe `keepAlive` becomes false?

Comment: No, it only becomes false in `onDestroy()`. Assume it is always true

Comment: Which OS version are using?

Comment: @Sagar on Android 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background):

> When an app goes into the background, it has a window of several
>   minutes in which it is still allowed to create and use services. At
>   the end of that window, the app is considered to be idle. **At this
>   time, the system stops the app's background services, just as if the
>   app had called the services' Service.stopSelf() methods**.

Starting from `Android O` OS enforces several restrictions on how freely the background services can be executed. X minutes after app's exit, the services will be terminated as if `stopSelf()` was called. You need to use `ForegroundService` if you still want to continue but you need to consider impact on battery life. If you perform CPU intensive work, then usage of `ForegroundService` won't help.

You can refer to my answer in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566426/can-i-still-have-a-data-logging-background-service-in-android-8-0/49568651#49568651) for further details.

Comment: Thank you. I just have a problem: ForegroundService is not a class I can extend. How can I create a foreground service?

Comment: You need to extend it as normal Service. The way it is called is changed. Instead of calling `startService()` you will call `startForegroundService()` check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397754/android-implementing-startforeground-for-a-service)