# Oreo infinite background service like Messenger or Instagram

Tags: android, android-service, android-wake-lock, android-doze

How can I create an `infinite background service` without notification like Messenger, Instagram or HID Mobile Access?

For example HID Mobile Access has background service that runs infinitely, is not killed by system, does not have notification and is not restarted when app is removed from recent-app-list.

Is there any trick to do that or are there apps unofficially supported by Google?

Comment: they do not use `"an infinite background service"` - instead they use `FCM` or similar mechanisms

Comment: They are visible on "Running services" list in Dev options in Android. How can I use FCM in that way?

Comment: maybe your intention of creating such a service is wrong? what acttually do you want to achieve? why do you need such a service?

Comment: I am trying to implement an event trigger mechanism after user makes a gesture.

Comment: Have you checked my answers on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639229/run-background-services-on-battery-saver-mode-android/49641208#49641208) & [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566426/can-i-still-have-a-data-logging-background-service-in-android-8-0/49568651#49568651)

Comment: @piotrek00 did you check my answer?

Comment: Yes, and finally I've decided to use foreground service. Instagram and HID Mobile Access have target SDK 22 or 23 so their services do not have to be foreground and are allowed to work infinite.

Answer (score 0):

One option is you can use [Work Manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) to schedule tasks and run them in the background.

> The task is still guaranteed to run, even if your app is force-quit or
>   the device is rebooted.

Below is one example to run **Recurring tasks**:

```
new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder photoCheckBuilder =
        new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(PhotoCheckWorker.class, 12,
                                        TimeUnit.HOURS);
// ...if you want, you can apply constraints to the builder here...

// Create the actual work object:
PeriodicWorkRequest photoCheckWork = photoCheckBuilder.build();
// Then enqueue the recurring task:
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(photoCheckWork);
```

Answer (score 0):

These are either preinstalled "frameworks" - meaning these are non-restricted apps already pre-installed by the OEM device manufacturer. Those have special permissions.

OR as others explained they simply use FCM for receiving messages anytime. Though I agree it's unfair to charge app developers in order to bypass platform restrictions. Though it's free up to 100K messages/day (IIRC).

Nonetheless, do note that Whatsapp uses a foreground service (with always present and visible notification) in order to provide the [`Whatsapp Web`](https://web.whatsapp.com/) functionality.